# Is $y=\frac{1}{3x^2+12x-5}$ an quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is $y=\frac{1}{3x^2+12x-5}$ an quadratic equation? And how to find the coordinates of the turning point?

Comment: It is a rational function.

Comment: It's rational, but not quadratic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not.

A quadratic is of the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$. $\displaystyle \frac{1}{3x^2+12x-5}$ isn't even a polynomial!

The turning point, or vertex, occurs at the point $\displaystyle x=-\frac{b}{2a}$. It is a minimum if $a$ is positive, and a maximum if $a$ is a negative.

However, if your function is of the form $\displaystyle y=\frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}$, there is still a turning point at $\displaystyle x=-\frac{b}{2a}$. It is a maximum if $a$ is positive, and a minimum if $a$ is negative.

Comment: How to derive $x=-\frac {b}{2a}$

Comment: ax^2 + bx + c = a(x^2 + b/a x + c/a) = a(x^2 + b/a x + b^2/4a^2) + (c-b^2/4a) = a(x+b/2a)^2 + (c-b^2/4a)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean? On the one hand,
$$
\frac{1}{3x^2+12x-5}
$$
is not a quadratic polynomial.  On the other hand, the equation
$$
y=\frac{1}{3x^2+12x-5}
$$
is equivalent to
$$
3x^2+12x-5-\frac{1}{y} = 0
$$
which is a quadratic equation in the variable $x$.

I guess "turning point" is not a feature of a quadratic equation, but it is a feature of a quadratic polynomial.